# Firebase onIdTokenChanged function documentation

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm reading some Firebase auth docs, and I was confused by this line:

```
onIdTokenChanged ( nextOrObserver :  Observer < any > | ( ( a :  User | null ) => any ) ,  error ? :  ( a :  Error ) => any ,  completed ? :  firebase.Unsubscribe ) : firebase.Unsubscribe
```

I understand that this is a function signature, however, I'm not sure if I understand it correctly.
Is it the same as below?

```
firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(function(user) {
 //here some code related to user
},
function(error){
//here is some code if there is an error, this callback is optional
},
function()=>{
//a function triggered when the observer is removed, it is optional too
})
```

Also, what is `nextOrObserver :  Observer < any >` ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`onIdTokenChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) serves the purpose of keeping the legacy behavior of [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged), which was updated to backward-incompatible in version 4 of Firebase.

From the documentation:

> […] this triggered the observer when users were signed in, signed out, or when the user's ID token changed in situations such as token expiry or password change.

---

> Also, what is `nextOrObserver :  Observer < any >` ? Thank you.

This describes the following usage (note object as the single argument of `onIdTokenChanged`):

```js
firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged({
  next(user) {
    // ...
  },
  error(error) {
    // ...
  },
  complete() {
    // ...
  },
});
```

[image]